# How come FireFox came out with another release a week latter? Was a threat discovered?

Tags: web-browser, updates

I updated to FireFox 13 last week and today I got a message about there being a security update and upgrading to FireFox 14. Was a major security threat found? What justified the release of version 14 why not 13.1?

Comment: Googling the Firefox Wikipedia article would have given you the answer.

Comment: Despite your assumption there was a security threat, this is not a security question. Also it will be outdated in 6-8 weeks :-)

Comment: Reading the version release dates, why did Firefox switch from updating every year to every month? I mean I could see it happening if they were comercial and wanted people to buy their new product but they're not.

Comment: Read the article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox 13 was released on June 5th, 2012. Firefox updates to a new major version every ~6 weeks. Firefox 14 was released today. New features include Windows 8 support (Metro interface).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Firefox#Version_14